# moment is giving me error in angular 5 html template

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-moment, angular2-moment

I am using moment v2.22.0 in angular 5, and this is how I have imported it in module -

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and using it in component as -

```
export class ChatComponent {
  .
  .
  .
  public moment: any = moment;
  .
  .
}
```

and when I am using it in html template -

```
<div>{{moment(activeTeam.createdAt).format('LL')}}</div>
```

it is giving me an error message that -

```
[Angular] Member 'moment' is not callable
```

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong !!

Answer (score 22):

cli (run in console)

```
// install moment js
npm install moment --save
```

component declaration (ts)

```
// import and declare moment
import * as moment from 'moment';
moment: any = moment;
```

template file (html)

```
// template syntax
<p>{{moment(date_time_variable).format('ll')}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any advantage/ disadvantage of using moment directly in HTML rather than .ts file.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `any`, declare without it

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
moment = moment;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any particular reason for not using any.

Answer (score 4):

Try to import `moment` as :

```
import  moment from 'moment';
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{getFormat(activeTeam)}}</div>
```

TS:

```
getFormat(activeTeam){
   return moment(activeTeam.createdAt).format('LL')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

Will there be any performance issue if a similar code is used with ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring moment's type as any, declare it as `moment: () => any;`

Answer (score 0):

remove `* as` form import

For install `moment` from `npm install moment --save`

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/moment-is-giving-me-error-in-angular-5-html-template52037686520?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
import  moment from 'moment';

export class ChatComponent {
  moment: any = moment;
}

<div>{{moment(activeTeam.createdAt).format('LL')}}</div>
```